# When I start the next.js project with yarn, I get an error that the module does not exist

Tags: next.js

The next.js project was created using yarn. The commands used are as follows
However, I get an error that the module does not exist in the editor.
The error is resolved after re-installing with npm.
But with yarn, I get an error.

I tried to re-create the project and still got an error if it was yarn. I also get an error with yarn in all editors.

**Commands used**

```
yarn create next-app
yarn install
yarn cache clean
yarn build
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that dependencies by default are no longer installed under node_modules, if you're looking for that behavior, add to `.yarnrc.yml` the following line:
`nodeLinker: node-modules`